# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: No authorized routine named 'LIKE' of type 'FUNCTION' having compatible arguments was found

Tags: jpa, int

I am trying to search a database for an int (usually the id number) and then return all the details about this id number to the user. I have the following query:

```
public List<Userdetails> searchByInt(int parseInt) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM Userdetails u WHERE u.id LIKE :pattern");
    q.setParameter("pattern", parseInt);
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

However, it threw the following exception:

```
WARNING:   Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: No authorized routine named 'LIKE' of type 'FUNCTION' having compatible arguments was found.
Error Code: -1
Call: SELECT ID, USERNAME FROM USERDETAILS WHERE ID LIKE ?
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Userdetails sql="SELECT ID, USERNAME FROM USERDETAILS WHERE ID LIKE ?")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1995)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2714)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2667)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1114)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1202)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2894)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1797)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1779)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1744)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:468)
    at Richard.beans.UserdetailsFacade.searchByInt(UserdetailsFacade.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4695)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:630)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor113.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:582)
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Please try to learn to separate the concerns. This problem has got nothing to do with JSF. You'd have had exactly the same problem when invoking it as a plain Java application with `main()` method. You should then leave out the JSF from the question as it didn't play any role in causing the problem and thus only adds irrelevant noise to the question making your problem to unnecessarily look like more complicated. I've done it for you on this question and a couple of your previous questions. This has to stop :)

Comment: Ah sorry, i thought it would be best to list all the components and frameworks i used, sorry :) i will try to narrow it down more next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The predicate `LIKE` is meant to check if a text corresponds to a pattern.

To check for equality just use `=`. In you case:

```
SELECT u FROM Userdetails u WHERE u.id = :pattern
```

Answer (score 2):

The `LIKE` predicate, which seems to be implemented as a function in your database engine, is normally applied to character operands, while you seem to be trying to use it with integers. Your database tries to find the `LIKE` function that accepts integer arguments, but it's not there.

Answer (score 1):

I think using LIKE with an ID makes no sense (if ID is a NUMBER (Oracle) or an INTEGER (SQL '99)) Try using equasion (=).

`SELECT .... WHERE id = :pattern`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
LIKE VARCHAR('%'||USER.NAME||'%')
```

Instead of:

```
LIKE '%'||USER.NAME||'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I Used Derby Database and tried to TIMESTAMP column. So it **needs to convert to CHAR before using the LIKE.**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CAST(column AS CHAR(28)) LIKE '%2023-01-17%';
```